# How to call function of model in view file in django

Tags: python, django

I was created def function in model.py file and now i want to get this function in view.py file. I know how to get this function in template file but i dont know how to get this function in view file
for example:
In model.py file:

```
 class CartItem(models.Model):
        # cart = models.ForeignKey("Cart")
        cart = models.ForeignKey(
            'Cart',
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        product = models.ForeignKey(product_models.Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        item = models.ForeignKey(product_models.ProductDetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.item.title

        @property
        def item_week_real_total(self):
            return self.item.get_week_price() * self.quantity
```

In view.py file

```
cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(cart_id=request.session['cart_id'])
        for cart_item_data in cart_item:
            week_total = cart_item_data.item_week_real_total()
```

But i got error 'decimal.Decimal' object is not callable

Comment: It should give you a line where the error occurred?

Comment: error occured at week_total = cart_item_data.item_week_real_total()

Comment: just remove the parentheses `()` from `cart_item_data.item_week_real_total()` and use it as `cart_item_data.item_week_real_total`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item_week_real_total
```

should be called like a property/attribute, not a method. You decorated it with `@property` so it should be called like:

```
cart_item_data.item_week_real_total
```

without the `()`